# What does it mean when it says "path does not exist"

Tags: r

Good afternoon , i come back to you with code i received my professor with the intention to read variables and to compress all the files into one and run an equation with three variables. I am a novice at R and am receiving an error when i attempt to run the code

```
stns=read_excel("stn.xlsx")
Error: `path` does not exist: ‘stn.xlsx’
```

Im assuming that this is where R will place the output data so i created a blank excel spreadsheet with stn.xls but it returns the same error
I perfromed a traceback and this is what it responded with:

3: stop("`path` does not exist: ", sQuote(path), call. = FALSE)
2: check_file(path)
1: read_excel("stn.xlsx")

and here is the code for context:

```
library(seacarb)
library(readxl)
library(lubridate)

setwd("C:/Users/JNunl/OneDrive/Desktop/FileT/Lake Michigan")

myf=list.files(pattern="csv")

para=c("YEAR", "MONTH", "STATION_ID",            "STN_DEPTH_M",            "LATITUDE",                "LONGITUDE","SAMPLING_DATE","SAMPLE_DEPTH_M","DEPTH_CODE",               "MEDIUM",                "SAMPLE_ID",   "VALUE_1",        "VALUE_2", "VALUE_3")



result=NULL

for(i in 39: length(myf)){
  
  out=read.csv(myf[i],header=T)[para]
  
  result=rbind(result, out)
  
}


colnames(result)=c("Yr","Mn", "Stn","Std","Lat","Lon","Sdt","Spd","Dc", "Med", "SID",    "Alk",    "pH", "T")

a=subset(result, Med =="surface water")
a$Alk=as.numeric(a$Alk)
a$pH=as.numeric(a$pH)
a$T=as.numeric(a$T)
a$Mn=month(as.Date(a$Sdt))
a=subset(a, Alk>50 & Alk<125)

a=subset(a, !is.na(Alk) & !is.na(pH) & !is.na(T))

b=carb(flag=8, var1=a$pH, var2=a$Alk/50000, T=a$T, S=0.2, P=1, Pt=0.3e-9, Sit =10e-6, k1k2="r", pHscale ="F")

a$DIC=b$DIC*12000

a$pCO2=b$pCO2

stns=read_excel("stn.xlsx")

bsn<-function(x) if(nrow(subset(stns, STATION==x))>0) subset(stns, STATION==x)$BASIN else NA

lon<-function(x) if(nrow(subset(stns, STATION==x))>0) mean(subset(stns, STATION==x)$LONGITUDE) else NA

lat<-function(x) if(nrow(subset(stns, STATION==x))>0) mean(subset(stns, STATION==x)$LATITUDE) else NA


a$Basin=unlist(mapply(bsn, a$Stn), use.names=F)
a$Lat=unlist(mapply(lat, a$Stn), use.names=F)
a$Lon=unlist(mapply(lon, a$Stn), use.names=F)`
```

Comment: try formatting your question so its easier to read ``` using these three characters to start and end your code will make it into a code chunk

Comment: The error is not to do with writing to a file.  It is in the line `read_excel("stn.xlsx")`. R is telling you that there is no file call `"stn.xlsx"` in your working directory, which we can see you have set to `"C:/Users/JNunl/OneDrive/Desktop/FileT/Lake Michigan"`.